# Edge color gradient using Cytoscape.js circle layout

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I am using Cytoscape.js latest version (which, as of this writing, is 2.6.3) and using a Circle layout. Can we specify the color of the edge (line) to be the gradient of the color of the nodes which the edge connects? So for example, if the edge connects two nodes whose color are red (source) and green (target) respectively, can the edge color start from red (from source node) and slowly transition to green (to target node)?

I know it is possible using [D3.js](https://d3js.org/) but can we achieve something similar in Cytoscape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradients are not supported in Cytoscape.js, because in general gradients are not performant for large visualisations.

If you want to request a new feature, please use the issue tracker: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues

Answer (score 0):

For documentation purposes, this appears to have been added in a recent release, issue closed https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/2091